# multiple forms on page submitting to first form?

Tags: forms, jsf

I have three forms in  one page, each calls  a different backing bean, but when i use a form  other than the first one the call goes three times to the first form, each form persists into a  DB.Table  and the  persistence is being done  three times when i click the  commandButtons, is this bad practice or am I missing  something in my code ?

```
    <h:form id="ciclista-form" >            
        <div id="ciclista-link"><h1>Crear Ciclista</h1></div>
             // inputTexts ...  ..  .
        <h:commandButton action="#{ciclistaBean.guardarCiclista()}" value="Guardar Ciclista"  class="ciclista-form-btn"/>   
    </h:form>       
    <h:form id="Etapa-form" >    Etapa-form              -->
        <div id="Etapa-link"><h1>Crear Etapa</h1></div> -->
             //  input texts . ..  
        <h:commandButton action="#{etapaBean.guardarEtapa()}" value="Guardar Etapa"  class="carrera-form-btn"/>  -->
    </h:form>  Etapa-form -->

    <h:form id="carrera-form" >    <!-- carrera-form -->                
        <div id="carrera-link"><h1>Crear carrera</h1></div>
             //   input texts . . . 
        <h:commandButton action="#{carreraBean.guardarCarrera()}" value="Guardar Carrera"  class="etapa-form-btn" />
    </h:form>  <!-- carrera-form -->
```

all calls  go to first form, why is this ?

Answer (score 0):

The snipped you show seems ok, what type are your beans? What scope do they have? Have they dependencies to another?

I tried to follow you idea with following code, it works in my setup...

```
<h:body>
    <h:form id="ciclista-form">
        <div id="ciclista-link">
            <h1>Crear Ciclista</h1>
            <h:inputText value="#{ciclistaBean.text}"/>
        </div>
        <h:commandButton action="#{ciclistaBean.guardarCiclista()}" value="Guardar Ciclista" class="ciclista-form-btn" />
    </h:form>
    <h:form id="Etapa-form">
        <div id="Etapa-link">
            <h1>Crear Etapa</h1>
            <h:inputText value="#{etapaBean.text}"/>
        </div>
        <h:commandButton action="#{etapaBean.guardarEtapa()}" value="Guardar Etapa" class="carrera-form-btn" />
    </h:form>
    <h:form id="carrera-form">
        <div id="carrera-link">
            <h1>Crear carrera</h1>
            <h:inputText value="#{carreraBean.text}"/>
        </div>
        <h:commandButton action="#{carreraBean.guardarCarrera()}" value="Guardar Carrera" class="etapa-form-btn" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

with three independend `@RequestScoped beans`

```
@ManagedBean(name = "ciclistaBean")
@RequestScoped
public class SO26836137_F1 {
    private String text;    
    public void guardarCiclista() {
        System.out.println("Form 1 submitted: " + text);
    }   
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }   
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}


@ManagedBean(name = "etapaBean")
@RequestScoped
public class SO26836137_F2 {
    private String text;
    public void guardarEtapa() {
        System.out.println("Form 2 submitted: " + text);
    }
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}


@ManagedBean(name = "carreraBean")
@RequestScoped
public class SO26836137_F3 {
    private String text;
    public void guardarCarrera() {
        System.out.println("Form 3 submitted: " + text);
    }
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

Comment: they are `@SessionScoped`

Comment: That does not make a difference. What about dependencies between the beans? e.g. heredity?

Comment: no all beans  are completely different from each other

Comment: Without seeing the code it's hard to guess... I would check 1) the sourcecode of yout html-page: are there three forms? 2) Make sure your forms ARE NOT NESTED in other forms! 3) sniff the traffic: do you see the submission of the correct form in the browser (F12). 4) debug jsf-lifecycle http://balusc.blogspot.de/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html